# Missing artifact org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-runtime:jar:0.8.1

Tags: eclipse, maven, cloud-foundry

Anybody know where cloud foundry runtime jar be found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cloudfoundry-runtime has been deprecated for some time now. Spring Cloud Connectors should be used instead as the preferred way for an app to inspect the CF environment that it is running in.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#spring-cloud-

Comment: I have an old Pom with the following entry

Comment: I'm a newbie in this area , I have an old Pom with the following entry   <!-- CloudFoundry -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
   <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
   <version>${org.cloudfoundry-version}</version>
  </dependency>   What do I replace this with?

Comment: I replaced it with  :-  ¬<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency> ¬

Comment: **but now get a name space_ conflict**

Comment: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cloud:data-source'.`

Comment: cloud datasource **Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-
  spring-0.8.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the 
  document is not <xsd:schema>.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
  'cloud:data-source'.**   What do I do to correct this?

Comment: It looks like you are using Spring XML configuration and it is also out of date. Try following the instructions and examples here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector#the-cloud-namespace.